# Taking a photo and show it in a ImageView of another activity

Tags: android

I have two activities: MainActivity and ShowPhotoDescriptionActivity. The first activity has a FloatingActionButton that when pressed, it starts the camera, takes the photo, saves it into a folder for this app. After that, the second Activity is called. This activity should show the last photo taken in an ImageView. It looks simple but nothing works.
I have already tried some solutions but most of them didn't resolve any of my problems.

In MainActivity i have

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Starts the device's camera
            dispatchTakePicture();

        }
    });

/**
 * Calls an existent camera app to take a picture, then is stores on device in a custom folder
 */
private void dispatchTakePicture() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "photocrowd" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            final String appDirectoryName = "Photocrowd";
            photoFile = createImageFile(appDirectoryName, imageFileName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ocorreu um erro: Não foi posível armazenar a foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Main Activity", "It wasn't possible to catch the photo: "+ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {

            Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a folder and a name to the image on the device
 *
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
private File createImageFile(String name_folder, String name_image) throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    final File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), name_folder);
    imageRoot.mkdir();
    File image = new File(imageRoot, name_image);

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}
/**
 * Allows the photo be found for the media scanner and shown in gallery
 */
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        galleryAddPic();
        //Once the photo is taken and saved, the description activity is called
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PhotoDescriptionActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("path", mCurrentPhotoPath);

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Alright, this just allows to take the photo, save in a folder named "Photocrowd", displays it in the gallery and sends the path to the other activity.

In  PhotoDescriptionActivity i have

```
private ImageView mImageView;
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_photo_description_activity);
    Log.v("DESCRIPTION", "Activite PHotoDescription");
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_panel);

    String imageRoot = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    Log.v("DESCRIPTION", imageRoot);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageRoot));

}
```

I have already tried to use other methods (using libraries, setImageUri, and others). The Path to imageRoot is the same showed on the photo description in my Android (`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photocrowd/photocrowd20170419_124851.jpg`)

This code was the last that I tried and it shows in Log:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photocrowd/photocrowd20170419_130554.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I wrote these permissions in Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

how can I just get this last photo already taken and saved in my gallery? I know it looks simple but nothing works.

Comment: Probably you forgot to ask the user to confirm the requested permissions. You use Android version >= 6? Google for runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not granted permission "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" as described in your log:
`E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photocrowd/photocrowd20170419_130554.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`.

This permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is dangerous permission and from Android 6.0, you need to request permission at runtime:

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality;

You can read more at [Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

For easy coding, I suggest using: [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) while it's easy to use and make your code much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks,with your explanation and what @greenapps said I could easily solve my problems. I didn't know the runtime permissions, so I read it's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and could do it.